# Google+ +1 Button Snippet+ Problem

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I have integrated the Google +1 button into a website ( http://www2.highpoint.edu ).

I tried to use schema.org `<meta>` tags to provide Name, Description, and Image for the +Snippets information, but it doesn't work.

When I use the +1 button and try to post to Google+ about the website, it picks an image that I don't want.  And it won't pick the image I have set with the `<meta>` tag.

My questions:

1. How do I get the +Snippet data populated from schema.org metadata?
2. For a page with 2 or more +1 buttons, can I have different name/description/image for each +1 button?  Or must every +1 button on the page use the same metadata?

**EDIT**

I think it is best to use Open Graph Protocol instead of schema.org. That is, schema.org shouldn't be used at all.  Facebook supports Open Graph Protocol, so you can kill 2 birds with 1 stone this way.

More importantly, Facebook provides a great debugging tool that tells you what exactly is getting parsed for a given URL:  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I am still not sure about having multiple +1 buttons on the same page with each +1 button having distinctly different meta data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to question 1:

I checked your page. It looks like you have a normal meta title and description. This should work for the +1 button, but it may take some time for the +1 button to pick up the changes you've made.

If you'd like control of the image, though, you will need to use schema.org markup or open graph as described in the official FAQ: http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/#plus-snippet

And for question 2:

If you are using schema.org markup, the +1 button will read the content for the itemscope nearest the top of the page's source code.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it another try.

Comment: add 2) - i tryed to configure +buttons contextualy, but without success. But i've done successfully schema.org data binding by metas relevant to whole html page - it worked. So i can recommend to bind buttons to concrete URLs and configure metas there. However i still use context schema.org for seo.

Comment: Got it. My answer to #2 was actually incorrect, as you've discovered. The +1 button and badge use the data from the itemscope nearest the top of the page's source code. The meta elements satisfy this well. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work for me either. I have both Schema.org and Open Graph in the web page (eg. http://r.mycrep.net/3Nkh/), Multiple validators (Facebook's and one other) read info correctly.

I guess that Google still does not support metadata for everybody :-(

Comment: I think Google has gotten better with Open Graph Protocol data parsing since I originally posted this.